# Current draw at digital output pin differences in two equally coded segments -probable cause?

Tags: arduino, avr, current, atmega

I measured the current output of an Arduino Duemilanove (with an ATmega168) in two cases and found out that the currents differ strongly.

The following code creates an output of 72mA at pin 13 measured in my case on a digital multimeter (Tenma 72-7745). Note that it is almost the double of the max. current of 40mA.

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);     
}

void loop()
{  
 digitalWrite(13, !digitalRead(13));  
 // digitalWrite(13, digitalRead(13) ^ 1); // this works as well
 delayMicroseconds(58); 
}
```

the code below about 36.5mA:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);     
}

void loop()
{  
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(58); 
  digitalWrite(13, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(58);
}
```

The measured frequency at pin 13 (+) and ground for both examples is around 8kHz.
The current draw doesn't change too much when I make the frequcey lower for example with  delayMicroseconds(1000); it is in this case 493Hz and 68mA in my condition (temperature and microinstructions which effects the clock I suppose).

I tried to google this, but could not find any sources. Do you have any idea?

Is this somehow related to the digitalRead() instruction? Does this function need a current to read? What about current sink and source? I need help..

Comment: Are you sure the first example is actually switching? I'm not sure but maybe `digitalRead` changes the DDR register to an input rather than reading data register directly.

Comment: That is interesting unless I am missing something. I am pretty sure the delayMicroseconds() functions are `inline` (at least the AVR gcc _delay_us() function is and surely Arduino uses it), but that really should not make much difference. Both loops are effectively the same in that they produce ~50% duty cycle @ ~>8000Hz considering the instruction fetch and execution times. What frequency and duty cycle are you seeing on your scope?

Comment: @PeterJ yes yes I can see the signal on an oscilloscope.. It is a squared wave :-)

Comment: Inevitably this is likely going to come down to average output voltage over time. What frequency and duty cycle do you observe on your scope? And what is your load?

Comment: If the measured 72mA is valid, then note that it's almost double of the datasheet stated absolute max current per I/O (40mA). You run the risk of damaging your chip.

Comment: I spedified the questio a bit. I don't get exactly with the question of my "load". The load is my "multimeter"?

Comment: First, you should not be shorting an output to ground through your meter to measure it (**with a lower impedance source, this would kill the meter or blow its fuse**).  Second, you have to realize that your meter is a sampled instrument not intended to measure pulsed currents, and so its reading may vary widely for even small changes in signal frequency or duty cycle.  **You should be measuring across a resistor sized to produce in-spec current, with an oscilloscope as the measuring device.**

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks will verify that later next week...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

digitalRead reads the state of the pin, not the value in the output register. If a heavy load is pulling the pin voltage low then it will read as logic 0 even if the output register bit is set to 1. Your first code example tries to toggle the output level by inverting the logic level found on the pin, but because it is always reading low the output will always be set high. Current is doubled because the output is 'high' 100% of time, not the 50% you expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So this means, we shouldn't use "digitalWrite(13, !digitalRead(13)); or "digitalWrite(13, digitalRead(13) ^ 1);" ??

Comment: or only with a resistor (125 Ohm for 5V)??

Comment: The maximum allowed output current is 40mA, which equates to 100 Ohms at 4V. This output voltage is well above the digital input threshold (about 2.5V). Adding a resistor >=100 Ohms in series will ensure that the pin cannot be overloaded by a short to ground, and you can use digitalRead to toggle the output.